# Always O(1) is better than O(n) in algorithm time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, time-complexity, big-o

I am asking that just think for a moment if I have an algorithm which is taking O(100) ---->O(1) time complexity and I have an algorithm for the same problem which takes O(n) to solve but if I know that it's n's maximum value is 50 then I can decide it's worst case is O(50) so in a case like this still O(1) algorithm or the second O(n) algorithm is the best choice? So if it's the second one, can we always tell O(1) is better than O(n) ?

Comment: Big O is a measure of _scaling_. If you have a fixed number of items, _every_ algorithm is O(1).

Comment: See this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35385/for-small-values-of-n-on-can-be-treated-as-if-its-o1

Answer (score 4):

Sure, not; not *always*. **Big O** is just an *asymptotic behaviour*, that's why

```
O(1) == O(0.001) == O(50) == O(100) == O(C) # where C is any positive constant
```

same for `O(n)`

```
O(n) == O(0.001n) == O(100n) == O(C * n)    # where C is any positive constant
```

imaging two algorithms with timings

```
t1 = 1e100 (seconds) = O(1)
t2 = n     (seconds) = O(n)
```

for the *infinite* `n` (asymptotic behaviour) the 1st algorithm is better than 2nd, but for all real world cases (small `n`) `t2` is preferable. Even scaling is not enough:

```
t1 = 1000               (seconds)
t2 = 100 * n            (seconds)
t3 = n + 1e100 * log(n) (seconds)
```

Algorithm 3 has a better scaling (`1` vs. `100` : `n` vs `100 * n`) but `1e100 * log(n)` term makes it impossible to finish in real world cases.

So instead of `O` in general case you should compare *functions*:

```
t1 = 100 (seconds)
t2 = n   (seconds)
```

here if `n <= 50` then `t2` is a better choice (and for `n > 1000` we have quite an opposite)

Comment: @Dimitry Bychenko Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Two algorithms:

```
100n -> O(n)

10n² -> O(n²)
```

If n < 10 the quadratic time algorithm is better. If n > 10 the linear time algorithm is better.

There are also practical use cases. Quick sort algorithms (avg: O(n log(n))) often uses insertion sort (avg: O(n²)) in case given data collection is small enough.

Comment: can you please explain your solution further more ? Because I don't see how that quadratic time algorithm is better in the cases of n>100.Ex:100.000*200 = 20000.000 and 10*200*200=400000 but still 400000 > 20000

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake. Corrected the values. ;)